# How to get all errors from lua json schema validation

Tags: json, lua, schema, json-schema-validator, error-list

I am able to work with lua json schema validators like [ljsonschema](https://github.com/jdesgats/ljsonschema) &[rapidjason](https://github.com/xpol/lua-rapidjson/blob/master/API.md) but noticed none of them give all the errors & they abort on the 1st error. 
Is it possible to get the complete list of errors if the input json has > than 1 validation issues ?

For ex:
For a schema like

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
     "foo" : { "type" : "string" },
     "bar" : { "type" : "number" } 
  }
}
```

The sample json : `{ "foo": 12, "bar": "42" }` should give 2 errors. However, I get only 1 error `property "foo" validation failed: wrong type: expected string, got number`.

How can I get both the below errors:

1. property "foo" validation failed: wrong type: expected string, got number
2. property "bar" validation failed: wrong type: expected number, got string

in the same run ?